# Calling variable when using Scanner Class and Multiple Classes

Tags: java, object, char, java.util.scanner, equation

Trying to call the total value from the operatorSelection class while that class references what the user enters as the operator.

I want it to end up coming out as number1 (operator chosen) number2...= total.

Not sure how to call class so that it prints the " System.out.println(number1+" "+operator+" "+number2+" "+operator+" "+number2+ " = "+ total); " correctly.

Any knowledge would be greatly appreciated on the subject.

Thanks.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class NumbersEntered 
{



public void operatorSeletion(double number1, double number2, double number3, char operator)
{
    double total = 0;


    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':
            total = number1 + number2 + number3;
            break;

        case '-':
            total = number1 - number2 - number3;
            break;

        case '*':
            total = number1 * number2 * number3;
            break;

        case '/':
            total = number1 / number2 / number3;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("You have entered incorrectly. Please try again.");

            return;
    }


}



}





public class JavaPresentation_KS {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    NumbersEntered nums = new NumbersEntered();
    Scanner equation = new Scanner(System.in);



    System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
    double number1 = equation.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
    double number2 = equation.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter third number: ");
    double number3 = equation.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    char operator = equation.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.println(number1+" "+operator+" "+number2+" "+operator+" "+number2+ " = "+ total);




}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you declare the `total` variable *within* the `operatorSeletion` method, and you try to  access it *without* specifying it's location. You need to declare the `total` variable as a field, and then access it at its location (`new NumbersEntered().total`). Also, you never invoke `operatorSeletion`, which might help ;)

```
class NumbersEntered {

public double total = 0; //declare as accessable field

public  void operatorSeletion(double number1, double number2, double number3, char operator)
{     
    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':
            total = number1 + number2 + number3;
            break;

        case '-':
            total = number1 - number2 - number3;
            break;

        case '*':
            total = number1 * number2 * number3;
            break;

        case '/':
            total = number1 / number2 / number3;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("You have entered incorrectly. Please try again.");

            return;
    }       
}
}
public class JavaPresentation_KS {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    NumbersEntered nums = new NumbersEntered();
    Scanner equation = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
    double number1 = equation.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
    double number2 = equation.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter third number: ");
    double number3 = equation.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    char operator = equation.next().charAt(0);

    nums.operatorSeletion(number1, number2, number3, operator); 
//invoke the method

    System.out.println(number1 + " " + operator + " " + number2 + " " + operator + " " + number2 + " = " + nums.total);
//Access at location (nums.total)   
    }
```